# Allow a variable to be accessed from different files in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I have 2 Javascript files. An `app.js` file and `productController.js`.

I'm setting a variable inside `app.js` and need to access it inside `productController.js`

```
.......
    const next = require('next')
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    const nextLoader = next({dev})
    const handle = nextLoader.getRequestHandler()

    nextLoader.prepare().then(() => {
        const app = express();

        app.use(cors());
        app.set('nextRender', nextLoader) <-----
.......
```

Then in `productController.js` im trying to use `nextRender` that I set in the `app.js` file.

```
const Product = require('../models/Product.js')

exports.listProducts = (req, res) => {
    nextRender.render(req,res, '/products')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app.js`, store your `nextLoader` object in `app` :

```
app.nextRender = nextLoader;
```

In `productionController.js` use `req.app.nextRender` :

```
exports.listProducts = (req, res) => {
    req.app.nextRender.render(req, res, '/products')
}
```